# hyper-v 2016 host stuck - vm's not responding

Tags: virtual-machines, hyper-v-server-2016

i have a windows 2016 host, with 3 vm's on it. it was working fine from the day it was installed.

4 months ago, i added another host, and started replicating it, with veeam and hyper-v replication.

Since then, i had 3 incidents, on which two of the vm's became unresponsive. It did not happen during a veeam replication. On the first two incidents, I restarted the host. On the 3rd, today, I tried looking more closely at what's going on - and i "solved" it by restarting the vmms service. This brought back the vm's to life. During this incident, i noticed, from the host, that the time on the vm was showing the date of last Friday.

This is a major problem - how do I start investigating it? I looked at the host logs, but there was no major event during that time.